# How best to convert decimal to integer?

Tags: sql, ruby

I am building a financial application with Ruby on Rails 4 and I need to store values such as `0.83423423432534634546` in the database (SQLite as well as MySQL).

I tried storing these values in the database as `decimals`.

However, I ran into some very nasty floating point errors, so I would like to store them as `integers` instead.

How can I convert a value like `0.4457546346354664233443` to an integer and vice versa?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You risk losing precision. Convert them to strings instead, it's safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your financial app simply can't use SQLite.

Values of type decimal(m,n) or numeric(m,n) aren't subject to floating-point errors unless they're being mishandled.

```
create table test (
  -- 15 digits left of the decimal; 20 digits right of the decimal.
  n decimal(35, 20)
);

insert into test values (123456789012345.83423423432534634546);

select * from test;
```

```
123456789012345.83423423432534634546
```

In *SQL*, arithmetic using decimal and numeric data types is done in numerics. But do arithmetic with a numeric and a float, and you'll get a float or a double in return. (This is one kind of mishandling.)

This works correctly in MySQL (above), but fails miserably--no error or warning--in SQLite (below).

```
sqlite> create table test (
   ...>   -- 15 digits left of the decimal; 20 digits right of the decimal.
   ...>   n decimal(35, 20)
   ...> );
sqlite>     
sqlite> insert into test values (123456789012345.83423423432534634546);
sqlite>   
sqlite> select * from test;
```

```
123456789012346.0
```

SQLite has *no* numeric or decimal data type<sup>1</sup>. And it only gives you 15 digits for columns besides text, regardless of what you tell it.

```
sqlite> delete from test;
sqlite> INSERT INTO "test" VALUES('123456789.123456789012345');
sqlite> select * from test;
```

```
123456789.123457
```

Declaring the column to be text preserves all the digits, but breaks arithmetic.

```
sqlite> drop table test;
sqlite> create table test (n text);
sqlite> INSERT INTO "test" VALUES('123456789.123456789012345');
sqlite> select n from test;
```

```
    123456789.123456789012345
```

```
sqlite> select n*2 from test;
```

```
246913578.246914
```

SQLite rounded the answer to 15 digits.

With Rails, I use only MySQL or PostgreSQL in development, test, *and* production environments. I use SQLite only when I'm fooling around.

---

1. SQLite has no *data types* at all, in the database sense. SQLite has what *it* calls *storage classes* instead. [Docs](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: Hi Mike. Your essay probably saved me from a lot of trouble. In fact I am using SQLite in development and I ran into a couple of (what I thought) floating point errors in the past. As a result I decided to store all money values as `integers` and convert them to `decimals` using getter and setter methods every time I deal with them in the views (which is actually quite cumbersome). So if I understand you correctly switching from SQLite to MySQL in development and then storing all money values in type `decimal` columns is the best way for me to go?

Comment: Yes, I think you should switch to MySQL in development. (I think *almost* every Rails developer should use the same dbms in dev, test, and production.) And, yes, use decimal(m,n) as the data type.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for your help. Your post has really opened my eyes. I wonder why they tell all the Rails newbies to start with an SQLite DB...

Comment: @Tintin81: SQLite doesn't require any setup. I'm pretty sure it's installed by default on all Linux distributions. It's simpler; you don't have to know any passwords, whether to use tcp/ip or a socket, which port to use, etc.

Comment: Yeah that's what lured me in too :-(

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is: If you want to keep the values with the maximum precision of n digits below the decimal point, then:

- original `value` to integer: `(value * 10 ** n).to_i`
- `integer` to original value: `integer / (10 ** n).to_f`

But if I were you, I would rather follow Sergio's suggestion.

Comment: Technically, this is the correct answer to my question but I will mark Mike's answer as the correct one since it prevented me from a lot of trouble in the future. Thanks for your help.